# PHP function Not giving any result

Tags: php, function

I am facing some problem in my PHP function.

```
function pagename($id){
$query=mysql_query("select * from tbl_pages where recid='$id' and langid='$LangID'")
$rs=mysql_fetch_array($query);
$page_name=$rsp['pgname'];
print  $page_name;
}
```

i am not getting any resutl

Comment: The `$LangID` variable not exists

Comment: where is the connection object? use mysqli

Comment: If we take this literally: there is no `return` statement.

Comment: I think `$rs` is not equal to `$rsp` with addition to @ThomasRollet's comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw some problems in your code

First, there is no connection string to your database, I hope you do the connection before to do the request.

Then, in your request, you try to use a variable **$LangID** not declared in your function, maybe you forgot to put it in your function declaration.

You put the result of your request in the **$rs** variable and then you try to read the **$rsp** variable.

You are using **mysql** in your code, actually it's very unsafe to use it, it's very recommended to use **mysqli** or **PDO** instead.

Finally, you don't return anything with your function, you are missing the **return statement** or maybe you just want to display the result ?

EDIT : I suggest you to write your SQL requests with uppercase, it's more readable for you and other people who read your code.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_pages WHERE recid='$id' AND langid='$LangID'
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no `$LangID` parameter.

$rs and $rsp are different variables in your code, you should use only one of them.

This function does not return anything, even if you get something in your print.

Check if mysql connection is already established.